# Are we using "Aswaddumization" word?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

"Aswaddumization"  is a derived word from Sinhalese language(Sri Lankan native language ) and gone to English (as I heard), the meaning of "Aswaddumization" is cultivation of land.

However, I cannot see this is used practically, please let me know if this is used in English language as an accepted word. I did search in Google but couldn't find a good reference.

Comment: A google found me http://thoughtfullines.blogspot.nl/2011_05_01_archive.html

Comment: Is it in a dictionary? (GR) Would random English person on the street understand its meaning? If the former can be answered "Yes", then it has been "accepted". If the latter can be answered "yes", then it is in use. If the word is used in a very specific (for instance, scientific) context not relevant to the general populace, it may be considered "accepted". Who's the audience? What problem does your question solve?

Comment: "BlanketyBlank-ization" is a commonly used idiom for modifying something to conform to "BanketyBlank" (whatever that is).  Thus the word above is valid if "Aswaddum" can be expected to be recognized by the listening audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the word is only used in Sri Lanka and is not common to other varieties of English. There is no entry in the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/).

However, English is a constantly evolving language and words are frequently assimilated from other languages when needed. If you wish to use it, then I would recommend giving a definition upon its first use, to help the unfamiliar reader. As a matter of style, I would always try to use the simplest word that conveys the meaning I wish; therefore, I would not use "aswaddumization" unless it has particular connotations that are not conveyed by by "cultivating the land". Perhaps, it refers specifically to the conversion of fallow land to a particular type of paddy field?

Comment: Actually, "Aswaddumization" gives more meaning (like digging soil, keep it until naturally get fertilized and planting seeds and finally getting the fruits out of it etc.) than the  cultivation word in English from Sinhalese point of view, however with your expert advice I will take your advice on using this word internationally. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Since there is additional meaning, there is a case for using it, just make sure to give it a clear definition. Eventually it may become incorporated into the standard, albeit specialised, lexicon. (Shame it's too long for Scrabble).

Answer (score 3):

Aswaddumization is derived from the Sinhala language. *Asswadduma* means cultivating land that has been fallow for ages. As an example if we clear a jungle area , irrigate the land and prepare it for paddy cultivation this can be called aswaddumization. Not every cultivation can be called asweddumization; only when it is making land newly cultivatable can asweddumization be used.

Comment: You say as an example, but then you follow this with the description of an example... Could you give an example of this in a sentence in English?